# Urban Airship Phonegap 3 - alias and tags not updating in android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, urbanairship.com

I am using Phonegap 3.0 with Urban Airships library and phonegap plugin.

I have created the sample app and I can see the apid listed in the UA console. However the tags and the alias are not updating.

It looks like tags are supposed to be set and if successful it will run the get tags function and is supposed to output them to the console. I am not seeing them output and in the urban airship 
console I am not seeing the tags setup either.

Any ideas on what to do next?

Comment: may i know your problem...what your facing...

Comment: I can't see any error messages - i guess i'm not sure how to debug on my phone? I created an APK in eclipse and installed the APK on my phone. When i fire the app up, the apid shows up on urban airship console, but i can't set tags aliases with the demo app. I don't know how to debug this further? where can i see error message from a devices etc?

Comment: even you try to enable debugger in your mobile/emulator and start in the eclipse run as debug your project.........